# NodeJS Exec cp with brace expansion gives different results. Why?

Tags: node.js, linux, macos, sh, brace-expansion

I have a grunt-shell command which cp images files using brace expansion.

```
file: Gruntfile.js
cpImgTmp: {
    command: 'cp ./app/images/{*.png,*.jpg,*.ico} tmp/images' 
}
```

When I run this grunt-shell command on MacOS, it does what is expected but returns 'cannot cp...' error on ubuntu.

I've searched through grunt-shell lib and noticed it uses exec function.
I tested the command once more in a controlled environment

`exec('cp ./app/images/{*.png,*.jpg,*.ico} tmp/images')`

and verified exec function's spawn args are the same:

`['/bin/sh', '-c', 'cp ./app/images/{*.png,*.jpg,*.ico} tmp/images']`

I successfully executed the command inside ubuntu server terminal. 
So my **question** is the problem with nodejs handling of brace expansion in different environments and what options can I pass to nodejs to make this command work cross unix OS?

Comment: Why not try `execFile('cp',['./app/images/{*.png,*.jpg,*.ico}','tmp/images'])` ... oh nevermind you can't with grunt-shell ... hmmm

Comment: @CodyG. Thanks for the reply! Even without using grunt-shell, `execFile('cp',['./app/images/{*.png,*.jpg,*.ico}','tmp/images'])` still doesn't work as expected in ubuntu.

Comment: does it work... from the command line in ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this is less of a nodejs problem but a unix shell issue which nodejs could avoid.

The issue is `sh` doesn't support brace expansions, `bash` does.
On my Mac, **`sh` is symlink to `bash`** and ubuntu (18.04) **`sh` is symlink to `dash`** (by the results this obviously doesn't support brace expansion).

Solution is to pass `{shell: '/bin/bash'`} for brace expansion to work in unix systems instead of the default '/bin/sh' shell.

example using NodeJS `exec` function: `exec('cp ./app/images/{*.png,*.jpg,*.ico} tmp/images', {shell: '/bin/bash'})

example using grunt-shell

```
cpImgTmp: {
    command: 'cp ./app/images/{*.png,*.jpg,*.ico} tmp/images',
    options: {
        execOptions: {shell: '/bin/bash'}
    }
}
```